# change current directory after ctrl+c in bat

Tags: windows, batch-file

I've a bat in windows, it looks like:

```
cd jetty
java -jar start.jar
```

At first, the bat file is at c:/project/ and there is also a jetty directory at c:/project/.
Before the bat is started, current directory is c:/project/. The bat file starts a jetty server.
Ctrl+C will stop the server. But now current directory is c:/project/jetty. If I want to run the bat file again, I must return to c:/project. How can I change directory back to c:/project after Ctrl+C.
p.s. The bat file can not be put directly in c:/project/jetty.
Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usually simply including an `cd ..` after the `java` command to return to the parent folder should work, but it is possible that the <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd> could also cancel the batch file.

You can use `setlocal`

This command is used to preserve the current environment contents (yes, it does more things, see `setlocal /?`, but not needed in this case) so when the batch context ends or a matching `endlocal` is executed the changes to the environment are discarded. One of the elements that are preserved is the current active directory.

```dos
setlocal
  cd jetty
  java -jar start.jar
endlocal
```

As the `setlocal` will be canceled if the next line in the batch script is reached or if the batch file is terminated, the previous active directory will be restored in both cases.

Comment: Thanks for your attention & answer. My problem is solved.

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what I needed - worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
cd jetty
java -jar start.jar
cd..
```

Comment: Thanks for your attention & answer.